# Core Data not firing fault when accessing relationship property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Im having some trouble figuring out why Core Data isn't firing a fault when i access an attribute in an entity relationship?

I have a feeling the reason might be due to the way I am subclassing my NSManagedObjects which is like so:

```
NSManagedObject
     |      
MYManagedObject (NSNumber *id)
     |
MYSimpleManagedObject (NSString *name)
     |
Employee
      \
       Manager
```

and

```
NSManagedObject
     |
MYManagedObject (NSNumber *id)
     |
MYSimpleManagedObject (NSString *name)
     |
  Manager
        \ 
      Employee
```

In the scenario above Employee and Manager are both subclasses of a couple of other Classes which are not in themselves Entities in my data model but rather regular classes i have used to encapsulate code *and* properties such as id and name which are common to a number of Entities. This model has worked really well for me however my problem is that the following statement does *not* fire a fault `manager.employee.name`

however if instead i use `[manager valueForKeyPath:@"employee.name"]` the fault is fired and i get the value i need.

Do i need to override any accessor methods or something in order for the value to fire a fault?

Answer (score 0):

In the model editor you can specify certain entities to have parent entities. I would recommend modeling both parent entities in Core Data and specifying the parent-child relationship.

In my experience, your accessors should then work as expected.

Comment: thx for the response however from what i understand from [this](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-models-and-model-objects.html) post, the Entity Hierarchy vs. Class Hierarchy section, if i follow the model you suggested then all subclass properties will be store in a common table? If i have numerous subclasses each with large datasets then this will store all that data in one table.

Comment: If you think you will suffer from a performance hit, just model the two attributes `id` and `name` in both your entity classes `Manager` and `Employee`. But I would not do this unless you are really hitting a performance problem.